# Powershell to loop each file

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here, haven't had a great deal to do with Powershell

I'm trying to get Powershell to:

1. Find all files in a given directory
2. Copy the first file to a "Master" file
3. Run the SQL Stored Procedure, which references the "Master" file
4. Powershell to them remove the "Master" file
5. Start again until no more files remain in the initial directory
6. Stop

This is my code I've come up with so far

```
Get-ChildItem '\\FolderPath\*.txt' 
 %{copy-item -path '\\FolderPath\*.txt' -destination '\\FolderPath\Master.txt' 
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=MYSERVER;Database=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "MYPROCEDURE"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]
        Remove-Item '\\FolderPath\Master.txt'
                    }
```

But once it's hit the first file, it stops and doesn't loop any further.

I thought for `%` it should loop??

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the alias for `Foreach` loop in PowerShell. You need to `pipe` your list of files to the `foreach` loop. `|` is the pipeline operator in Powershell. Your code will look like this -

```
Get-ChildItem '\\FolderPath\*.txt' |
%{copy-item -path '\\FolderPath\*.txt' -destination '\\FolderPath\Master.txt' 
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=MYSERVER;Database=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "MYPROCEDURE"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]
Remove-Item '\\FolderPath\Master.txt' }`
```